# Trouble with returning value from form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a select drop down box which will return a specific value when chosen, which is working fine. However i have tried to add number of adults text form to return that value when the same button is pressed and nothing works, it is confusing me because it seems that it should be simple but nothing i try is working, Here is my HTML:

```
        <form>
    <select id = "journeyList">
    <option name ="Bristol " value="40">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
    <option name ="London " value="35" >Bristol - London</option>
    <option name ="Glasgow " value="70" >Glasgow - Manchester</option>
    </select><br><br>
    </form>

    Number of Adults: 
    <form>
    <input type = "number" name ="adult" id="ofAdults" value="" required>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button><br>
```

Javascript:

```
function BookingFare() { 

        var journeyList = document.getElementById("journeyList");
        var price = journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value;

        var Adults = getElementById("ofAdults").value;
        //var ofChildren = getElementById('children').value;
        //var Discount
        //var Total
        //var SeatsLeft

        if (journeyList == 40) {
         var price = journeyList.value;
        }

        if (journeyList == 35) {
         var price = journeyList.value;

        }

        if (journeyList == 70) {
         var price = journeyList.value;
        }

        document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
        document.getElementById('adultsBox').innerHTML = Adults;

        }
```

It is only the returning value of adults that i am having issues with.

Comment: need document.getElementById("id").value; insted of id.value

Comment: try this and let me know are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/rm1xtdko/

Comment: thankyou for the improvement!

Comment: are you looking for that ?

Comment: it has fixed my issue, and simplified my code, so yes! thankyou!

Comment: your if statement will not work, you need to correct it in your scenario journeyList  is an object

Comment: if you want to do something then using if then  if (journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value== '40') {
        
    
        } is the right way

Comment: thank you for the advice! you have been the most helpful person yet.

Comment: ok happy to help you , i had posted an answer you can refer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<select id = "journeyList">
    <option name ="Bristol " value="40">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
    <option name ="London " value="35" >Bristol - London</option>
    <option name ="Glasgow " value="70" >Glasgow - Manchester</option>
    </select><br><br>


    Number of Adults: 
    <form>
    <input type = "number" name ="adult" id="ofAdults" value="" required>

    <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button><br>
        <div id="priceBox"></div>
               <div id="adultsBox"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function BookingFare() { 

        var journeyList = document.getElementById("journeyList");
        var price =journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value;

        var Adults = document.getElementById("ofAdults").value;

        document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
        document.getElementById('adultsBox').innerHTML = Adults;

        }
```

this will display the current list value and textbox value in your div

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rm1xtdko/)**

**Note1:**
your  if statement need some modification

in your case journeyList is an object so you can't directly do something like below

```
 if (journeyList == 40) {
         var price = journeyList.value;
        }
```

if you want to do something with if  then you must do like following

```
 if (journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value== '40') 

{ 
// your code goes here 

}
```

Note2: normally we are taking the select values in onchange event. So i thing it is better to use onchange event, then no need of a button click here you can see the details at the time of selection changed.

If you want it in that way then use following code

```
<select id = "journeyList" onchange="BookingFare();">
    <option name ="Bristol " value="40">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
    <option name ="London " value="35" >Bristol - London</option>
    <option name ="Glasgow " value="70" >Glasgow - Manchester</option>
    </select><br><br>


    Number of Adults: 
    <form>
    <input type = "number" name ="adult" id="ofAdults" value="" required>

    <button type="button">Submit</button><br>
        <div id="priceBox"></div>
               <div id="adultsBox"></div>
```

**js**

```
function BookingFare() { 

        var journeyList = document.getElementById("journeyList");
        var price =journeyList.options[journeyList.selectedIndex].value;

        var Adults = document.getElementById("ofAdults").value;

        document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
        document.getElementById('adultsBox').innerHTML = Adults;

        }
```

no need to click a button 
here

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rm1xtdko/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "document." when accessing ofAdults element.

It should be

```html
var Adults = document.getElementById("ofAdults").value
```